# Best way to track multiple sites with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, tracking, multiple-domains

I currently have 63 websites (and counting) that I'm tracking on one Google Analytics account, and I'm starting to realize... this is becoming a bit cumbersome.

What's the best way to collect traffic data in bulk?  Are there other resources out there that are better suited for this task?

Does Google offer a bulk option for this kind of thing?  Would it be better to make separate analytics accounts?

I'm just wondering if anyone else has had found a better solution that manually setting up all these accounts/setting up the tracking codes etc, when it comes to large scale management.

Comment: No matter what solution you are going for (Google Analytics, Reinvigorate, or others) it's going to be cumbersome. Heck, you have 63 sites to track and actually the tracking itself has no value to it, if you are not able to generate conclusions out of the data. Separate account are not going to help you either, imagine having 63 different accounts, loging in and out each time... I'd stick with GA or if you have the cash: have a look at Omniture ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are (cheap) solutions available, but it should not be too hard to track some basic stats yourself.

You could either have a DB setup that can be reached by all the website and track users using sessions and have data submitted to the database. Or you could have all websites save tracking data locally, and you have a script running on either the main site or your computer that collects (wget) all the files, and then parses them and throws the data into a DB. In either case the code would be easy to integrate into a CMS (which i assume you're using).

Comment: I'm not looking for a custom solution, or at least not at this point in time.  I'm looking for something already out there.

Comment: i assumed that you didn't, but i didn't wanna make an answer 'doubt it exists' and leave it at that ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's a difficult situation to be in.

Look into roll up reporting. Even still there are pitfalls using this method.

http://analytics.blogspot.com/2009/09/advanced-structure-your-account-with.html

Answer (score 1):

I have 450 websites and I track them all using [www.ogggy.com](http://www.ogggy.com/).

I can sort and organize domains into folders and you can drill down to individual domains and view analytics for each domain. Its a great multi tracking tool.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the custom alerts of GA? You can apply a custom alert to multiple profiles.

So if let's say your target is to increase the number of visitors in a website, you just create a custom alert. As soon as the number of visitors increases you will receive an email (or even an sms) about it.

Here are some [good examples](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/7-essential-google-intelligence-custom-alerts-that-keep-me-sane) of custom alerts.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Logaholic](http://www.logaholic.com) it lets me easily setup multiple profiles for multiple websites. I can grant different access rights to multiple users and it can read web-server logs as well. I think you can analyze thousands of websites from a single installation.

Comment: Does this work with Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd use the GA API to pull specific KPIs for each website into a summary dashboard, that would give you a quick overview of the important stuff for each site, then you can use GA directly to investigate anything that stands out. The initial setup would take a little time but once it's implemented it would make tracking performance a breeze.